# Ensure instance of typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, shapeless

if I have an ADT and a type class, is there a way for me to ensure at compile time that there is an instance of the type class for every subtype of the ADT?

Just to give an example - I'd really like this to not compile as there isn't an instance of `A` for `Baz`

```
sealed trait Foo
final case class Bar(s: String) extends Foo
final case class Baz(i: Int) extends Foo

trait A[T <: Foo] {
  type O
  def f(t: T): O
}

implicit val barA = new A[Bar] {
  type O = String
  def f(t: Bar): O = t.s
}
```

This is all my own code, so I'm happy to change the encoding of `Foo` if required (maybe a shapeless coproduct can help me out here?)

*EDIT*

Sorry, should have mentioned - I have a function a bit like this I'd like to implement (lets assume my instances are in an object I've imported and they are the only implementations in scope)

```
def g[T <: Foo](fs: List[T])(implicit a: A[T]): List[a.O] = fs.map(a.f(_))
```

From the comments below, it looks like I should also have said that the thing that calls `g` can do so with a `List` of any subclass of `Foo` (I have no control over that part other than to change `g` I guess). Here, I'm trying to ensure that if someone changes `Foo` later on, then there will be a compiler error letting the user know that they need to implement an appropriate `A`

Comment: Instance of a typeclass (or more generally implicit values) only have meaning in a given scope. Where do you want your instances to be defined?

Comment: Sorry - was concentrating so hard on the first part of the code, I didn't do the second part! Will edit now :)

Comment: You can't do dispatch depending on ADT subtype with implicits - implicits are resolved at compiletime, your specific case is runtime. So you'd have to define your `g` with e.g. shapeless.

Comment: awesome OK - I kind of wondered if I was getting in a muddle because I was trying to do a runtime thing at compile time

Comment: @Reactormonk I only know a small amount of shapeless - do you have any other pointers?

Comment: @Reactormonk How is this runtime? We still have no idea how `g` will be called, but its type `T` will be resolved at compile time. And if its call site scope has no implicit `A[T]` it will return a compilation error.

Comment: annoyingly, the thing that calls `g` can do so with any subclass of `Foo` - all I can guarantee is it is one of those subclasses :( my objective here is  to make sure that I have instances of `A` for all `Foo` so I can have some confidence in my code in case someone expands on `Foo` later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use F-bounded polymorphism (aka Curiously Recurrent Template Pattern):

```
sealed abstract class Foo[Self <: Foo](implicit val hasA: A[Self])
final case class Bar(s: String) extends Foo[Bar]
final case class Baz(i: Int) extends Foo[Baz]
```

`abstract class` is used instead of `trait` so the implicit is picked up automatically.

However, for this *specific* `A` and `g`, you may not really need a type class:

```
sealed trait Foo[O] {
  def f(): O
}

final case class Bar(s: String) extends Foo[String] {
  def f() = s
}

def g(fs: List[Foo[O]]): List[O] = fs.map(_.f())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trait Foo[T] {
  this: ImplementThis[T] =>
}

case class Bar() extends Foo[String] with ImplementThis[String] {
  override def f(t: String): String = {
    t
  }
}
case class Baz() extends Foo[Int] with ImplementThis[Int] {
  override def f(t: Int): Int = {
    t
  }
}


trait ImplementThis[T] {
  type O
  def f(t: T): O
}
```

Try something like this. This will enforce implementation of `def f(t: T):O` for any subclass of Foo that's defined.

```
def g[T <: Foo](fs: List[T])(implicit a: A[T]): List[a.O] = fs.map(a.f(_))
```

From this, I assume you want all the child classes of your Foo to have a `def f` so that they dont fail at runtime. I think my above suggestion will enforce that `def f` implementation and solve this problem.